# `no such package` when compiling TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm currently experiencing problems with compiling TensorFlow. It looks like there are problems downloading certain packages, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12979), however the last mention of the bug was in September. What is wrong? I simply cloned the latest r1.5 branch, ran `./configure` and tried to compile. I'm using cuda 9.1 with cudnn 7.

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda --config=mkl //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
........
ERROR: /home/mv310/projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:28:1: no such package 'third_party/eigen3': error globbing [**/*]: /home/mv310/projects/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/mkl_include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include (Too many levels of symbolic links) and referenced by '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:included_headers_gather'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package' failed; build aborted: no such package 'third_party/eigen3': error globbing [**/*]: /home/mv310/projects/tensorflow/third_party/eigen3/mkl_include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include/include (Too many levels of symbolic links)
INFO: Elapsed time: 10.798s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (37 packages loaded)
    currently loading: tensorflow/core ... (11 packages)
```

Comment: Did you run ./configure ?

Comment: Yes -- I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, not using the `config=mkl` flag, tried 1.5-rc1 and master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try removing mkl_include dir and build again?

Comment: This really ought to be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the note @jdv. I'm new to SO and it would't let me comment on the main post without 50+ reputation :). Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @yifeif https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast

Comment: Annoyingly removing the tensorflow directory and re cloning the repo worked, so I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was working in the models project.  My issue was a leftover directory from a previous install.  Deleting the directory and doing a fresh clone helped.

```
rm -r -f models/research/syntaxnet/tensorflow
git pull --recurse
cd tensorflow
./configure
```

In the tensorflow directory, I think  you can also stash your changes and do a hard reset too.

```
git stash
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Finally, if all else fails, clean your bazel cache

```
rm -r -f ~/.cache/bazel/*
```